# Tesseract change Language iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, tesseract

Can anyone explain me how can I change the language from `eng` to `german`.

When i download the new library from the Google Side and I include this in the **tessdata** the result is NULL.

Can anyone help me please??

Answer (score 3):

I decided to write a new answer.

After testing it out myself, I think the problem is the files are not copied to your device correctly.

Check if 'tessdata' is included in the "Copy Bundle Resources".
You can find that by clicking on your project > target > build phases

if not, click on the + button to add the tessdata files. (Note: make sure "copy items into destination group's folder (if needed) is NOT checked, and "create folder references for any added folder" is CHECKED)

If that doesn't work, please find the method that is copying the tessdata to your app bundle, and check the error that it is returning.

Hope that works for you.

Comment: Hi, i looked today at the build phases and i found the tessdata is included there. now, i see in the debug area i have a problem so my code find not the tessdata path.  2013-09-27 17:03:41.017 TesseractSample[5139:60b] image Orientation right
Error opening data file /var/mobile/Applications/7A640C6F-C8DC-4C51-814C-B21EDF9D6868/Documents/tessdata/deu-frak.traineddata
Please make sure the TESSDATA_PREFIX environment variable is set to the parent directory of your "tessdata" directory.
Failed loading language 'deu-frak'

Comment: How are you loading the tessdata to your application? do you have a method like this: `NSString *tessdataPath = [bundlePath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"tessdata"];
        NSError *error = nil;
        if (tessdataPath) {
            [fileManager copyItemAtPath:tessdataPath toPath:dataPath error:&error];
        }
        
        if (error) {
            NSLog(@"%@", [error localizedDescription]);
        }`

Comment: i have the same code as you. except of error code. i play a few of hours with my app and now it works. i have currently no idea what was the problem but i think the problem was loading the tessdata. now works due+eng. i must analyze what i to now but i think i have in my code instead of @"tessdata" dataPath. thank you for help. without your help i have now idea.

Comment: No problem. I had the same problem as you. Please use the error code, because it will tell you your problem. And use breakpoints to help you debug your problem in the future. Good luck to you!!

Comment: Can you tell me why the recognition works fine in portrait mode but not in landscape mode?? what i forgot to include in my app?

Comment: I had the same error and the solution was that .traineddata files have to be in your "tessdata" folder and the folder has to be in the root of the project.

Comment: I'm also experiencing this problem, only with German.  I have english and french and they work fine.  I added deu.traineddata to the same folder as the other files that work, but if german is in there, it fails.